SIMD Softmax implementation
I am learning SIMD and looking for feedback. This is column-wise Softmax for matrices stored in row-major format.
Note that matrices come from outside so padding or dimensions being power of 2 can't be guaranteed, hence unaligned load/stores and such.
I am using Google Highway, and my tests pass on several x86-64 versions and Apple Silicon
HWY_ATTR void RMSoftmax(std::span<const float> in, std::span<float> out,
                        uint32_t cols) {
  using D = hn::ScalableTag<float>;
  constexpr D d;
  using V = hn::VFromD<D>;
  const size_t rows = in.size() / cols;
  size_t split = cols & ~static_cast<size_t>(hn::Lanes(d) - 1);
  size_t c = 0;
  for (; c < split; c += hn::Lanes(d)) {
    V max = Set(d, -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity());
    const float* HWY_RESTRICT base = in.data() + c;
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
      max = Max(max, LoadU(d, base));
      base += cols;
    }
    base = in.data() + c;
    float* o = out.data() + c;
    V accum = Zero(d);
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
      V exp = Exp(d, Sub(LoadU(d, base), max));
      accum = Add(accum, exp);
      StoreU(exp, d, o);
      base += cols;
      o += cols;
    }
    base = in.data() + c;
    o = out.data() + c;
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
      StoreU(Div(LoadU(d, o), accum), d, o);
      base += cols;
      o += cols;
    }
  }
  std::array<float, hn::MaxLanes(d)> maxs;
  maxs.fill(-std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity());
  for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
    const float* HWY_RESTRICT base = in.data() + r * cols + split;
    for (size_t c = 0; c < cols - split; ++c) {
      maxs[c] = std::max(maxs[c], base[c]);
    }
  }
  std::array<float, hn::MaxLanes(d)> sums;
  sums.fill(0);
  for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
    const float* HWY_RESTRICT base = in.data() + r * cols + split;
    float* o = out.data() + r * cols + split;
    for (size_t c = 0; c < cols - split; ++c) {
      o[c] = std::exp(base[c] - maxs[c]);
      sums[c] += o[c];
    }
  }
  for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
    float* o = out.data() + r * cols + split;
    for (size_t c = 0; c < cols - split; ++c) {
      o[c] /= sums[c];
    }
  }
}


I couldn't compile this due to missing the function Exp so I guess you've implemented that youself, could you add that to make the code compilable?

It's in https://github.com/google/highway/blob/master/hwy/contrib/math/math-inl.h

Make your code more readable
At a first glance, this code is unreadable. It's very dense, and lots of one-letter variable and type names are used. I would go over the code and do the following:

Expand one-letter names to something more meaningful. It doesn't have to be very long, just make it concise.
Split your code into multiple sections. A good start might be to separate the four outer for-loops with whitespace.
Document the code. Either add some comments to explain what each section of the code does, or even better, add helper functions for each of those sections. With a well-chosen name, a function documents itself.
Consider creating new types. For example, create a class MatrixView that contains a std::span with the matrix elements and a variable cols to remember its shape. You could add member functions that return a row and/or column at a time. This simplifies RMSoftmax() and makes what you are doing more clear. From C++23 on you should use std::mdspan.

Ideally, your code will look something like:
HWY_ATTR void RMSoftmax(MatrixView<const float> in, MatrixView<float> out) {
    FirstStep(in, out);
    auto maxs = SecondStep(in);
    auto sums = ThirdStep(maxs, in, out);
    FourthStep(sums, out);
}

Of course, with better names for the four functions that are called from RMSoftmax().
Consider creating a version for aligned POT matrices

Note that matrices come from outside so padding or dimensions being power of 2 can't be guaranteed, hence unaligned load/stores and such.

Depending on the CPU architecture, that might miss out on some amount of performance if the input and output are in fact properly aligned, power-of-two matrices. It's quite easy to check this though. Consider creating a second version that handles that case, and call it from RMSoftmax() if the input is suitable.
You should benchmark the two versions to see if there is any benefit at all from creating a version that works on aligned, power-of-two matrices.

Using aligned operations is not important anymore IMO, you'd have to look back quite a few years for that to really matter - these days as long the address is aligned, an unaligned load/store still takes advantage of the alignment (so you can use the same code for both cases)

@user555045 Aligning maxs and sums with alignas, however, may help performance, depending on whether the compiler ever needs to spill them.

@Davislor perhaps. They're only used for the non-SIMD handling of the left-over columns though, not for SIMD loads and stores
